# Login conditioned by droplist Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to make login for 2 types: Admin & Regualar users, each one had diff table, where I`ll check the type by dropdownlist,

problem:
it won`t get into if statement that check the type. 
how to make it check what`s the value of the droplist and depends on that it`ll decide to check in which table.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Threading


Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public s As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Session.Clear()

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim userCount As Int32 = GetUserCount(txtUserName.Text)
    Dim paasCount As Int32 = GetPassCount(TxtPassword.Text)
    Dim userCount2 As Int32 = GetUserCount(txtUserName.Text)
    Dim paasCount2 As Int32 = GetPassCount(TxtPassword.Text)
    Dim x As String = DrpType.SelectedValue

    If x = "Admin" Then
        If userCount2 > 0 And paasCount2 > 0 Then
            Session("FirstName") = txtUserName.Text
            Response.Redirect("LoggedIn.aspx")
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Admin')", True)
        Else
            lblErr.Visible = True
        End If


    ElseIf x = "Cus" Then
        If userCount > 0 And paasCount > 0 Then
            Session("FirstName") = txtUserName.Text
            Response.Redirect("LoggedIn.aspx")
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Customer')", True)
        Else
            lblErr.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub


' Method to check existence for users
Public Shared Function GetUserCount(ByVal userName As String) As Int32
    Const sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Registration where username = @UserName"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql1, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName)
            con.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    reader.Read()
                    Dim count As Int32 = reader.GetInt32(0)
                    Return count
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function


' Method to check PAssword for users
Public Shared Function GetPassCount(ByVal password As String) As Int32
    Const sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Registration where password = @Password"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql2, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password)
            con.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    reader.Read()
                    Dim count As Int32 = reader.GetInt32(0)
                    Return count
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function


        ' Method to check existence for admin
Public Shared Function GetUserCount2(ByVal userName2 As String) As Int32
    Const sql3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Adm_Login where username = @UserName"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql3, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName2)
            con.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    reader.Read()
                    Dim count As Int32 = reader.GetInt32(0)
                    Return count
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function


         ' Method to check PAssword for admin
Public Shared Function GetPassCount2(ByVal password2 As String) As Int32
    Const sql4 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Adm_Login where password = @Password"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RegconnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql4, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password2)
            con.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    reader.Read()
                    Dim count As Int32 = reader.GetInt32(0)
                    Return count
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function


Public Sub DrpType_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DrpType.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

End Class
```